# Poison: How to decode to structs when the json value could be an object, or a list of objects

Tags: elixir, elixir-poison

I'm trying to decode a the following json strings using Poison

```
iex(1)> fetch(1)
{:ok,
 "{\"name\":\"Anabela\",\"surname\":\"Neagu\",\"gender\":\"female\",\"region\":\"Romania\"}"}
iex(2)> fetch(2)
{:ok,
 "[{\"name\":\"Juana\",\"surname\":\"Su├írez\",\"gender\":\"female\",\"region\":\"Argentina\"},{\"name\":\"ðíðÁÐÇð│ðÁð╣\",\"surname\":\"ðƒð╗ð¥Ðéð¢ð©ð║ð¥ð▓\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"region\":\"Russia\"}]"}
```

Doing a `fetch(1) |> decode_response` won't work although it is for param strictly sup to 1.

I do have the following error

```
10:07:52.663 [error] GenServer Newsequence.Server terminating
** (BadMapError) expected a map, got: {"gender", "female"}
    (stdlib) :maps.find("gender", {"gender", "female"})
    (elixir) lib/map.ex:145: Map.get/3
    lib/poison/decoder.ex:49: anonymous fn/3 in Poison.Decode.transform_struct/4
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1262: :lists.foldl/3
    lib/poison/decoder.ex:48: Poison.Decode.transform_struct/4
    lib/poison/decoder.ex:24: anonymous fn/5 in Poison.Decode.transform/4
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1262: :lists.foldl/3
    lib/poison/decoder.ex:24: Poison.Decode.transform/4 Last message: {:getpeople, 1} State: {[], #PID<0.144.0>}
```

My function is as below :

```
def decode_response({:ok, body}) do
    Poison.decode!(body, as: [%Personne{}])
end
```

I then think for param equal to 1, function should be

```
   def decode_response({:ok, body}) do
        Poison.decode!(body, as: %Personne{})
    end
```

I finally thought it was a good idea to count tuples within the string given by my fetch function and use a guard to choose which decode_response to use, but i don't know how.

May someone please point me on the right direction ?

Regards,

pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first decoding to native map/list using `Poison.decode!/1`, then calculating the relevant value for `as:`, and then finally calling `Poison.Decoder.decode/2` with the native data structure and the structure to decode into:

```
def decode_response({:ok, body}) do
  parsed = Poison.decode!(body)
  as =
    cond do
      is_map(parsed) -> %Personne{}
      is_list(parsed) -> [%Personne{}]
    end
  Poison.Decoder.decode(parsed, as: as)
end
```

Demo:

```
defmodule Personne do
  defstruct [:name, :surname, :gender, :region]
end

defmodule Main do
  def main do
    f1 = {:ok, "{\"name\":\"Anabela\",\"surname\":\"Neagu\",\"gender\":\"female\",\"region\":\"Romania\"}"}
    f2 = {:ok, "[{\"name\":\"Juana\",\"surname\":\"Su├írez\",\"gender\":\"female\",\"region\":\"Argentina\"},{\"name\":\"ðíðÁÐÇð│ðÁð╣\",\"surname\":\"ðƒð╗ð¥Ðéð¢ð©ð║ð¥ð▓\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"region\":\"Russia\"}]"}

    f1 |> decode_response |> IO.inspect
    f2 |> decode_response |> IO.inspect
  end

  def decode_response({:ok, body}) do
    parsed = Poison.decode!(body)
    as =
      cond do
        is_map(parsed) -> %Personne{}
        is_list(parsed) -> [%Personne{}]
      end
    Poison.Decoder.decode(parsed, as: as)
  end
end

Main.main
```

Output:

```
%{"gender" => "female", "name" => "Anabela", "region" => "Romania",
  "surname" => "Neagu"}
[%{"gender" => "female", "name" => "Juana", "region" => "Argentina",
   "surname" => "Su├írez"},
 %{"gender" => "male", "name" => "ðíðÁÐÇð│ðÁð╣",
   "region" => "Russia",
   "surname" => "ðƒð╗ð¥Ðéð¢ð©ð║ð¥ð▓"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little naive, but it'll save doing a second parse of the JSON:

```
if (body |> String.trim_leading() |> String.starts_with?("[")) do
  Poison.decode!(body, as: [%Personne{}])                    
else                                                       
  Poison.decode!(body, as: %Personne{})                      
end
```

Note, if you are on Elixir 1.2 or below then you'll want to use `String.lstrip/1` instead of `String.trim_leading/1`.

Another way to do it would be to decode it as a map, use [String.to_existing_atom/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/String.html#to_existing_atom/1) to convert the keys, then use [Kernel.struct/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#struct/2) to convert into structs.

```
  def decode_response({:ok, body}) do
    body |> Poison.decode!() |> string_map_struct(Personne)
  end

  defp string_map_struct(entry, module) do
    params =
      entry
      |> Enum.map(fn {key, val} ->
        key = to_existing_atom(key)
        {key, val}
      end)
      |> Enum.into(%{})
    struct(module, params)
  end

  defp to_existing_atom(key) do
    try do
      String.to_existing_atom(key)
    rescue
      ArgumentError -> key
    end
  end
```

Comment: Was looking for something a bit more simplier (like Dogbert solution below), but i will carefully have a look at yours. Seems really interesting .